# Java: Apache Qpid implemented with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jms, qpid

I'm new to Qpid and I'm trying to set up the environment.
After having read tons of documentations I managed to download the Apache Qpid and have it run in localhost:8080

I have also installed maven, cmake. Now I'm trying to start a new maven project in Eclipse to send a simple message. I'm not familiar with the API interface and concept at all.
Do I have to include any kind of jar in my project's solution or how do I make use of the server?

I have found as well this https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms. I have cloned it but I don't know how to use it. I read github's documentation but I'm still wondering around...

When I'm trying to run a simple hello world example in qpid-jms maven project I get the following errors.

[image]

Comment: Had you already a look at the [hello world example](https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/blob/master/qpid-jms-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/jms/example/HelloWorld.java)? What have you tried so far exactly? Did you get any error message?

Comment: Yes I did try to run a simple hello world. I edited mentioning the errors.

Comment: A `maven` project and a `missing ant file` looks like a problem with the project setup in Eclipse (not yet further investigated). How did you import / open the project in Eclipse?

Comment: File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project -> qpid-jms but I'm still getting a Maven configuration Problem even though I went to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings and changed User Settings to maven\con\settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should first check it outside the IDE. See below checklist and compare it in your environment

1. download the broker from https://qpid.apache.org/download.html
2. start the broker

   ```
   cd ${broker_home}/bin/
   ./qpid-server
   ```
3. compile `qpid-jms`

   ```
   cd ${qpid_jms_repo_home}
   mvn install -DskipTests
   ```
4. run the `Hello World` example

   ```
   cd qpid-jms-examples/
   mvn package dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime -DskipTests
   java -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* \
       -DUSER=admin \
       -DPASSWORD=admin \
       org.apache.qpid.jms.HelloWorld
   ```

   - amend the user name and password if you don't use the initial default values from the broker
   - the queue `queue` must be created before executing `HelloWorld`, otherwise the execution fails with a `javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException`